# Sample Silverlight Applications

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to get more Silverlight knowldge.

It would be usefull to study a number of Silverlight applications so am looking for links to some best practice/sample applications that I can download and study.

Answer (score 1):

Learn the MVVM pattern... most common architecture for silverlight apps / event driven model:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458800.aspx

Blessings,

Jeff